# How to successfully set up executables in R

Tags: r

How do I set up an executable in R such that I can then use `Sys.which()` to find it?

For example,I want to find `wget` with `Sys.which('wget')` however R cannot find, it returns and empty string. The path it should produce is located at:

```
'C:\\windows\\System32\\wget.exe'
```

Comment: Hello, please check `Sys.getenv("PATH")`

Comment: on my Windows installation, `wget.exe` isn't present in `System32`, the nearest I can find is `Sys.which('where')`

Comment: @Waldi I had to install into that directory to get it there. Once there I should then have the opportunity to call from `system`.

Comment: @Waldi this was actually very helpful. Turns out `Sys.which()` would select any file if it was in there. This just means the file was not added to `Windows32` properly and so it does not appear. Its correct in saying that `Sys.which('wget')` would work if it was there.